# Drawing rotated text in a image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My application insert a label and has two sliders rotate and scale the text. After I want to draw this text in a image. See the code of the sliders and method to draw the text.

```
- (IBAction)angleSliderDidChange:(id)sender {
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleSlider.value * M_PI / 180.0);
    [myNewLabel setTransform:transform];
}

- (IBAction)scaleSliderDidChange:(id)sender {
    [myNewLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:21*scaleSlider.value]];
    [myNewLabel sizeToFit];
    [myNewLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:17*scaleSlider.value]];
}

- (IBAction)editionDidFinish:(id)sender {
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:17*scaleSlider.value];
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName:font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle};

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bigImageView.frame.size);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGPoint contextCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(myNewLabel.frame), CGRectGetMidY(myNewLabel.frame));
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, contextCenter.x, contextCenter.y);
    CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, angleSlider.value * M_PI / 180);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, scaleSlider.value, scaleSlider.value);
    [myNewLabel.text drawInRect:(CGRect){-myNewLabel.frame.size.width/2, -myNewLabel.frame.size.height/2, myNewLabel.frame.size} withAttributes:attributes];
    finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    bigImageView.image = finalImage;
}
```

It is a simple procedure but my text is not being drawing in the same place of the added label. I believe I am forgoting some details but I can't see it. And the result is shown on the image below. So, please, help me to fix it.

[image]

Comment: Why did you change font of `myNewLabel` in `scaleSliderDidChange` twice? I believe the problem here is with `CGContextTranslateCTM`. Adding a little offset here and there should simply resolve the problem you are facing. Is there a UINavigationBar in the UIViewController you are doing this?

Comment: I change the font twice in order to have a space between the text and the border. Observe I use `sizeToFit` after the first a font adjust. I tested using just one changing and the result was the same. I am not using UINavigationBar.